# Post result from a query via php in same page with Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

I have a form on my website with 3 drop-down boxes. After user select an option from each one and hit submit the data is posted to an external php file, that makes an query to MySQL and then the page is reloaded and result posted. I'd like to make this more fancy - with ajax without reloading the page. the problem is I'm completely nube. I search interned and tried a couple of examples but no result. Here is the code:

**HTML FORM:**

```
<form name="showprice" id="showprice" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<select name="country" id="country">
<option value="">Select Country</option>
</select>
<select name="industry" id="industry" onchange="setOptions(document.showprice.industry.options[document.showprice.industry.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="">Select Industry</option>
</select>
<select name="quality" id="quality">
<option value=" " selected="selected">Select country and industry first.</option>
</select>
<input value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<script  type="text/javascript">
var frmvalidator = new Validator("showprice");
frmvalidator.addValidation("country","req","Please select country");
frmvalidator.addValidation("industry","req","Please select industry");
frmvalidator.addValidation("quality","req","Please select quality");
</script>
```

NOTE: I have removed the options to save space.

**The external view.prices.php:**

It is in another folder and now I am calling the result with

```
<?php include('includes/view.prices.php'); ?>
```

Present code is:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include ('config.php');
$con1 = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
if (!$con1)
{
die(<b>Could not connect: </b> . mysql_error());
}
echo'<br /><br /><table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
**some table headers (8 columns)**
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>';

$cou = $_POST['country'];
$ind = $_POST['industry']; 
$qua = $_POST['quality'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $ind WHERE quality=$qua AND desig=$cou ORDER BY id ASC" or  die('<b>Data Insert Error:</b> ' . mysql_error());

echo("<tr>
**Some table results with 8 variables taken from the MySQL database**
</tr>");

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con1))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
}
echo    '</tbody>
</table>';
mysql_close($con1);
}}
else {
echo '<div class="grid_9">
<p><b>TIP:</b> Pick country, industry and quality from the drop-down above and hit "Submit" button to view results.</p>
</div>';
}
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: You should add some input escaping (see [PHP.net documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)) for the `$cou = $_POST['country'];` and the following lines for security.

Comment: These values (all 3) are not inserted manualy. The user should choose from drop down menu, so no special characters can be passed as there are not any.

Comment: It would be easy to change the request, and add your own value, if you wanted to break the security.  It's best policy **never** to trust anything that is submitted, even if you think you know what is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

I'd investigate jQuery. You will want to disable the default handler:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Then with jQuery you can do something like:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '',
        data: $("#showprice").serialize(),  dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if( data['status'] == 'success' )
            {           
              // Do stuff here
            } 
        }
    });
```

That code assumes that you're going to return a json encoded string. Which jQuery can handle without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I use jQuery for this all the time.

```
$(function() {
    $('#showprice').sumbit(function() {
    $.post('includes/view.prices.php', $(this).serialize(),function(data) {  
    $('#idoftag').html(data);
    })
    });

})
```

Comment: Thanks you both, but as I said I am complete noob with java/ajax. I tried ~10 of examples, but I think I am missing something, so the best solution is if you can tell me step by step what and where to change.

Comment: What kind of problems are you having. The browser (I use safari) console should give you the javascript error and the php error should be inserted into the html element you have set. BTW the $('#idoftag') is the tag (ie. <div id="tagid">) you want to have the php output to.

Comment: 1. I am setting the form tag action=""
2. Add the above js code before the head tag
3. Link to jquery.min.js is added in the head
4. After the form I have <div id="idoftag"></div>
5. When I fill the form and hit submit, page reloads and no output. But I am sure the php script is working, as I get results at present state of the code.

Comment: Sorry you need to add return false just before the closing tag. That will prevent the page from refreshing

Answer (score 0):

With some help from a friend I've managed to do this:

1) In head of the file where is the form add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var working = false;
$('#id-of-form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if(working) return false;
working = true;
//$('#submit').val('Sending..');
$.post('path-to-php-file-to-be-executed',$('#id-of-form').serialize(),function(msg){
working = false;
//$('#submit').val('Submit');
$('#id-of-div-where-result-will-be-outputed').html(msg);
});
});
});
</script>
```

2) After the form add the div for outputed data

```
<div id="output_div"></div>
```

3) In path-to-php-for-execution add:

```
if(isset($_POST['id-of-form-field-1']) && isset($_POST['id-of-form-field-2']) && isset($_POST['id-of-form-field-3'])) {

// some queries here

}
```

That's all

Answer (score 0):

in your form, reference your current page as the action value...example, if your page is index.php. then use action="index.php" and method = "post". within the div you want the data to appear, write the php code in the correct format and enclose all this code with an         if($_POST){ -your database retrieval code - } ?>. This means that your post action will call the same page which will make the condition surrounding your code to be true, hence executed. Hope this helps, it nagged me back then but i this worked.

Comment: This does not use Ajax, so it doesn't really answer the users question.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, it looks like your { } are mismatched.  They line up when I deleted one after the die statement and one above the else.